# Does std::unique have a size limit?

Tags: c++, vector

I noticed that std::unique was not acting the way it should when I had a vector with a size of about 2000.  I tried unique with a smaller vector and it performed as expected.  I tested this by adding about 30 duplicate entries in the middle of both vectors.  In the smaller vector, unique put those extra 29 entries at the end of the vector, as expected.  However, in the larger vector, only one entry of the duplicate entries is there.  Is it possible that there is some limit that I am exceeding?  The same code was used for both the large and small vectors.

```
sort(dbaselista.begin(),dbaselista.end());
vector<string>::iterator lasta = unique(dbaselista.begin(),dbaselista.end());
//dbaselista.erase(lasta, dbaselista.end());
```

As a quick example,

Small vector: 19AB 175D 12AC 19F7 19F7 19F7 19F7 209C 20AF

Result: 12AC 175D 19AB 19F7 209C 20AF 19F7 19F7 19F7

If i ran the same code with a much larger vector, 19F7 would only exist once.

Comment: It's best to demonstrate issues with the actual code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only thing that `std::unique()` promises to do is return a range in which duplicates have been removed.  After the function runs, the items beyond the new end iterator that it returns are not required to be anything, so they can be anything.

Comment: Okay, that looks like what is happening with the larger vector, and it still seems to work.  Just curious, though, why doesn't it follow the same conventions as with the smaller vector in filling the items beyond the new end iterator?  Also, the nice thing about the functionality with the smaller vector is that I can identify which entries are the duplicate ones.

Comment: @MarkHsiung: I don't know why it behaves differently on the two inputs, but I know the higher-level reason why the standard explicitly makes no guarantees about how it will behave on those past-the-new-end elements: it's so that some unknown future optimisation, which leaves unchanged the behaviour of the function on the `[start, new_end)` range but happens to cause the rest of the range to be treated differently, can still be implemented (thus speeding up all programs that call `unique()` without violating the standard.

Comment: @MarkHsiung: A good library may account for things such as cache line sizes. Moving elements within a single cache line is practically free, moving them to another cache line is far more expensive.